# ISPConfig set up reverse DNS

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, web-hosting, ispconfig-3

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1.

I set up many websites and emails, but when I send an email to a certain email address I have the following error:

```
Your server IP address [186.156.31.17] does not have a valid reverse
550-DNS entry [pc-17-31-156-186.cm.vtr.net]. see
550-http://spamauditor.org/best-practices/check_dynamic_reverse_dns/
for
more 550-information. Protection provided by MagicSpam 2.1-8.3 550
http://www.magicspam.com (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

How can I set up reverse DNS in ISPConfig? I learned that I need a PTR record but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you can configure from your end unless your ISP has specifically given you the ability to do it.

Linode, for example has a button for it, but if you don't, you would need to contact your ISP.

Normally individuals don't have access to the rDNS records